# HtmlAgilityPack | Wrongly retrieved table nodes

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack, nodes

Hi there I've just registered on this website, because I need some help.

**I want to get results from the nyaa.eu website.**

Basically:

- Table Node is called `<table class="tlist">`
- Every row node is called `<tr class="tlistrow">` also sometimes it's **'trusted tlistrow'** etc.
- The Nodes I try to retrieve are: `<td class="tlistname"> <td class="tlistsize"> <td class="tlistsn"> and <td class="tlistln">`

Firstly I'm retrieving a table which contains all the info about torrents:

```
HtmlNode hnTable = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='tlist']");
```

So, next thing is retrieving all the rows which contains 'tlistrow' in its class attribute:

```
HtmlNodeCollection hncRows = hnTable.SelectNodes("//tr[contains(@class,'tlistrow')]");
```

And finally the problem is when I read every node it's always the same one:

```
foreach (HtmlNode row in hncRows)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode child in row.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (child.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='tlistname']") != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something found!\n\n" + child.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='tlistname']").InnerText);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The text displayed in the messagebox is always the same, it looks like it only selects one node multiple times.

How can I fix this or if I am doing anything wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    foreach (HtmlNode child in row.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (child.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='tlistname']") != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something found!\n\n" + child.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='tlistname']").InnerText);
            break;
        }
    }
```

**You need to understand the difference between** *relative* **XPath expressions and** *absolute* **XPath expressions**.

A relative XPath expression is evaluated off (having as an initial context node) a specific node in the XML document.

An absolute XPath expression is evaluated against the whole XML document (having as initial context node the document-node).

Any XPath expression that starts with the character `/` is an absolute XPath expression.

Based on the provided code, you want to use a relative XPath expression with an initial context node, containd in the variable named `child`.

The problem is that the expression you are using:

```
//td[@class='tlistname']
```

starts with `/` and is therefore an absolute XPath expression.

This, passed to the `SelectSingleNode()` method always selects the first `td` element in the whole XML document, that has a `class` attribute with string value `"tlistname."`

**Solution**: Use a relative XPath expression, such as:

```
.//td[@class='tlistname']
```

Comment: Yay, that was the simplest fix I've ever seen. Thank you so much! I actually have never read about XPath, so that's why I failed...

Comment: @KonradPiesiak: You are welcome. XPath is a most amazing, powerful and elegant language (and these qualities grow in versions 2.0 and 3.0). It deserves a systematic learning.

Answer (score 0):

The `//` [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) in the expression will look anywhere in the document for matches. Remove that when you don't need it.

So, try something like:

```
HtmlNode hnTable = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='tlist']"); 
HtmlNodeCollection hncRows = hnTable.SelectNodes("/tr[contains(@class,'tlistrow')]");
foreach (HtmlNode row in hncRows)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode child in row.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (child.SelectSingleNode("/td[@class='tlistname']") != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something found!\n\n" + child.SelectSingleNode("/td[@class='tlistname']").InnerText);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```